# Перевод фокуса на элемент управления

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть форма с двумя кнопками, называющимися aButton и bButton. Хочу, чтоб по нажатию мышкой на aButton выполнялась функция myFunctionMouseClickA, а по нажатию мышкой на bButton выполнялась функция myFun2. При этом, если (в том числе, сразу после нажатия мышкой на aButton) нажать энтер, должна выполняться функция myFunctionEnterPressed. Как можно это сделать?

То есть, как я понимаю, мне надо добиться того, чтоб после нажатия мышкой на aButton срабатывала функция myFunctionMouseClickA (для этого я её свяжу с событием mouseClick), а в фокусе после этого оказывалась bButton. Последнее и представляет для меня трудность.

Comment: Похоже, это решает проблему:  this.ActiveControl = null;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589814/setting-focus-on-another-control-on-button-click

Comment: Если решает проблему - оформляйте как ответ ;)

Comment: Я не уверен, это ведь перевод фокуса просто куда-то, а хотелось бы на конкретную кнопку. Сейчас буду разбираться, правда ли это полностью решает проблему. Просто недавно c sharp изучаю, поэтому мне нужно время.

Comment: Используйте метод [Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx). В обработчике клика пишем: `bButton.Focus();`

Comment: "Просто недавно c sharp изучаю, поэтому мне нужно время. " Если у вас есть (или будут возникать) вопросы, которые сложно конкретно сформулировать, то у нас есть система чатов, где могут помочь. [Список всех комнат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ru.stackoverflow.com), [C#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--), [F#](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)

Comment: Спасибо, @AlexanderPetrov, как я понял, именно это мне и надо.

Comment: Спасибо, @FoggyFinder, про чаты я не знал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может помочь

```
this.ActiveControl = null;
```

Но лучше вариант, предложенный в комментарии Alexander Petrov:

> Используйте метод [Focus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx). В обработчике клика пишем:
>
> ```
> bButton.Focus();
> ```